# I need to add a space and newline in my code

Tags: python

I am working on a homework problem and I cannot figure out how to add the space and newline. I have tried numerous changes.

Problem:

> Write a loop to print all elements in hourly_temperature. Separate elements with a -> surrounded by spaces.

Sample output for the given program:

Input:

```
90 92 94 95
```

Output:

```
90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95
```

Note: 95 is followed by a space, then a newline. The newline should be included only once, after all the items.

Here's my attempt to solve the problem:

```
user_input = input()
hourly_temperature = user_input.split()

for item in hourly_temperature:
    if item != hourly_temperature[len(hourly_temperature)-1]:
           print(item, end = " -> ")
```

Comment: When, exactly, do you want to print the space and newline?  After each item?  Or only once, after all the items?

Comment: Only once, after all the items.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure I understand the question. what is 95 referring to?

in python to print a new line print '\n' and it will print a new line, to print a space use a literal space

```
>>> print("This ends with a space then a newline \n")
This ends with a space then a newline 

>>> print("This will show up \nas two lines")
This will show up 
as two lines
>>>
```

Comment: Everything I have tried makes each number have a space and new line, not just the last number

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. Nathaniel Ford's answer is the one you want then,or something like it. Make the string, then print it rather than printing as you go

Answer (score 2):

Find the latest data in the array and print a new line if found :

```
if item == item[-1]:
  print("\n")
  print(item, end = " -> ")
else:
  print(item, end = " -> ")
```

Comment: Iterating over the array is not necessary to get to the last item. Also, you have a `if item = item[-1]` which assigns the last element of the array to item - a conditional that is always true. You want `if item == ...`

Comment: @NathanielFord `if item = item[-1]` is actually a SyntaxError.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Fair! It isn't in all languages, and I forgot that it was in Python. Suffice to say it's one of two syntax errors that are made here.

Comment: Using this with the double equals gave me a syntax error after the print("\n)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a couple of issues, starting with your input:

```
>>> user_input = input()
90 92 94 95
>>> user_input
'90 92 94 95'
>>> user_input.split()
['90', '92', '94', '95']
```

This does not actually contain a newline character, but even if it is, you can quickly remove it like so:

```
hourly_temperature = user_input.split()[:-1]
```

Finally, it's probably easiest if you use `join` to print:

```
print(" -> ".join(hourly_temperature))
```

`join()` is a method on all strings that takes an array that says "Glue each item in this array together using the original string." So a quick way to glue together numbers with commas is: `", ".join([1,2,3])`.

It may be that your instructions were saying you needed to include a space and newline at the end - it's unclear, but a `input()` call will not, on it's own, include this.

Another way to do this, if you need to add something to the end is to use f-strings:

```
printable_output = "{} \n".format(" -> ".join(hourly_temperature))
print(printable_output)
```

This results in:

```
>>> user_input = input()
90 92 94 95
>>> hourly_temperature = user_input.split()[:-1]
>>> printable_output = "{} \n".format(" -> ".join(hourly_temperature))
>>> print(printable_output)
90 -> 92 -> 94 

>>>
```

(Note the last element is dropped because I'm dropping the last element on the line I split `user_input`. I don't think it's necessary to do that - and if not just remove the `[:-1]`.)